# How to get data from _GET_ORDERS_DATA_ report type through c# code

Tags: c#, amazon-mws

I have a web application through which I am trying to connect to Report API of amazon MWS. I have downloaded "amazon-mws-v20090101-csclient-2014-09-30.*V325001841*.zip" file and added MarketplaceWebService folder in my application and in website application added its reference. All ok so far. Now I want to get data from _GET_ORDERS_DATA_ report. Is there any documentation/step which suggest how this method works? Does this report return the response as an object so that I can parse it and save the relevant fields in database?

While trying https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html when I select Reports - GetReportRequestList  I am not getting the report type _GET_ORDERS_DATA_. Any idea how this works?

**UPDATE**: I have done this coding and this is working so far and got this response:

```
<GetReportListResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-01-01/"><GetReportListResult><HasNext>False</HasNext></GetReportListResult><ResponseMetadata><RequestId>49dp24d3-b63t-4762-98a7-c25yc378051a</RequestId></ResponseMetadata></GetReportListResponse>
```

Code:

```
try
                        {
                            GetReportListRequest request = new GetReportListRequest();
                            request.Merchant = merchantId;
                            //request.Marketplace = marketplaceId;
                            request.AvailableFromDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);

                            TypeList t = new TypeList();
                            t.Type.Add("_GET_ORDERS_DATA_");

                            request.ReportTypeList = t;

                            MarketplaceWebServiceConfig config = new MarketplaceWebServiceConfig();
                            config.ServiceURL = "https://mws.amazonservices.com";

                            MarketplaceWebService.MarketplaceWebService service = new MarketplaceWebServiceClient(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, applicationName, applicationVersion, config);

                            GetReportListResponse response = service.GetReportList(request);

                            string xml = response.ToXML();
                        }
                        catch (MarketplaceWebServiceException ex)
                        {
                            Response.Write(ex.Message);
                        }
```

I want a list of all SKU for which there were any sales between the From Date and To Date so I will need a SKU number and the total quantity sold in that period But how do I get data from _GET_ORDERS_DATA_?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an order number then it's better to use [Amazon MWS Orders API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/orders/2013-09-01/index.html)

And use GetOrder and ListOrderItems to get order's details

Comment: Previously I was using Order API but since I have 100's of orders and fetching order id and making another request to fetch the order details seems not much feasible

Comment: I want to get SKU, purchase date and quantity Sold details and I am new to Amazon MWS so not sure which will be efficient Order API or Report API?

Comment: You can pass upto 50 order ids in orders api. But if you are trying to use reports api, Its bit tricky. I am not sure about c# but in PHP you request a report and you get report_request_id and then you do getReportRequestList to check the status of your report using report_request_id. Once the status says 'Done' you call GetReportList to get report_id and then you can call GetReport using report_id

Comment: have a look at this flow chart http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/reports/Reports_Overview.html

Comment: what about the throttling in oredrs API?

Comment: They say that "The GetOrder operation has a maximum request quota of six and a restore rate of one request every minute" in https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/orders/2013-09-01/MWSOrdersApiReference._V322383903_.pdf

Comment: The ListOrderItems and ListOrderItemsByNextToken operations together share a maximum request quota of
30 and a restore rate of one request every two seconds

Comment: You can do 2 request which basically have 50 order ids in one request so 2 request means requesting data for 100 order ids. If you do 6 request which is 300 order ids when you might have to sleep for a minute and process next request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107017/discussion-between-user1254053-and-keyur).